# Return a cell array based on string name in it

Tags: python, arrays, string

```
A=[['Upper_lower_torque/SPH-Lower torque-Upper torque.1', 'DynGraphElement', {'fx1': 239761.59375, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'fz1': -299702.0, 'tx1': 0.0, 'ty1': 0.0, 'tz1': 0.0, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107, 'tmg1': 0.0}], ['Upper_lower_torque/REV--Lower torque.1', 'DynGraphElement', {'fx1': 239761.59375, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'fz1': -299702.0, 'tx1': 30411.0, 'ty1': -0.0, 'tz1': 24328.80078125, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107, 'tmg1': 38945.08272495708}]
```

Out of an analysis, I have for example the forces & moments of 2 joints, being a spherical (SPH) and a revolute (REV) one. These are stored in A per cell via ['name of the joint','elementtype',{six forces and moments}]. Let's say I want to return the SPH-joint (first cell), so the ['Upper_lower_torque/SPH.., 'DynGraph..',{'fx1':2391...}] out of the array by searching it on it's specific name, so containing the keywords SPH and Lower or Upper.

I know that you can search via the

```
if any("SPH" in s for s in A ):
```

but I can't make it work because preferably I want more keywords, so SPH and Lower or Upper e.g., and if they are in a cell, I want the cell (or cell index) to be returned, so eventually

```
['Upper_lower_torque/SPH.., 'DynGraph..',{'fx1':2391...}]
```

Does anyone knows how this can be done quite efficient?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to provide a function to do your boolean comparison, so you can pack everything together as:

```
def get_cell_element(data, comp, index=0):
    for element in data:  # for i, element in enumerate(elements) if you need the index
        if comp(element[index]):
            return element
```

Then you can easily search your list by providing comparison function (you can even search on different indexes), e.g.:

```
A = [
    ['Upper_lower_torque/SPH-Lower torque-Upper torque.1',
     'DynGraphElement',
     {'fx1': 239761.59375, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'fz1': -299702.0,
      'tx1': 0.0, 'ty1': 0.0, 'tz1': 0.0, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107, 'tmg1': 0.0}
     ],
    ['Upper_lower_torque/REV--Lower torque.1',
     'DynGraphElement',
     {'fx1': 239761.59375, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'fz1': -299702.0,
      'tx1': 30411.0, 'ty1': -0.0, 'tz1': 24328.80078125, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107,
      'tmg1': 38945.08272495708}
     ]
]

element = get_cell_element(A, lambda x: "SPH" in x and ("Lower" in x or "Upper" in x))
# ['Upper_lower_torque/SPH-Lower torque-Upper torque.1', 'DynGraphElement',
#  {'ty1': 0.0, 'fx1': 239761.59375, 'tmg1': 0.0, 'fz1': -299702.0,
#   'tz1': 0.0, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'tx1': 0.0, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107}]

element = get_cell_element(A, lambda x: "Lower" in x and "REV" in x)
# ['Upper_lower_torque/REV--Lower torque.1', 'DynGraphElement',
#  {'fx1': 239761.59375, 'fz1': -299702.0, 'tz1': 24328.80078125, 'fmg1': 402621.62557113107,
#   'tmg1': 38945.08272495708, 'ty1': -0.0, 'fy1': -121644.0, 'tx1': 30411.0}]
# etc.
```

Comment: That makes it perfectly clear! Thank you very much for the wonderful explanation, it really helps a lot!